# How to submit a form of JSF working with more than one database table, using JPA

Tags: jpa, jsf-2

I am trying to submit a form and store it in database using JPA.
DB tables: (i) Student (ii) Course
Entities: (i) Student (ii) Course (iii) Master
Facades: (i) StudentFacade (ii) CourseFacade (iii) AbstractFacade
Controllers: (i) StudentController (ii) CourseController (iii) StudentInfoController

Through StudentInfoController's create method, I am trying to create the record for both Student and Course. But I am getting Persistence Error.
Please Help.

```
    public String create() {
    System.out.println("START: create from MasterController");
    System.out.println("Creating Student.");
    System.out.println("Student Values: <" + current.getStudent().getStudentName() + " - " + current.getStudent().getDegree() + " - " + current.getStudent().getStudentId() + ">");

    Student stud = new Student();
    stud = current.getStudent();
    System.out.println("Got Student Facade");


    System.out.println("Student Created.");
    Course course = new Course();
    course = current.getCourse();

    course.setCourseId(new BigDecimal(stud.getCourseId()));

    course.setStudentId(stud);
    try {

        getStudentFacade().create(stud);
        getCourseFacade().create(course);


        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("CourseCreated"));
        System.out.println("END: create from MasterController");
        return "successful";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error Caught.");
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        System.out.println("END: create from MasterController");
        return "failure";
    }
```

Comment: Form submission has nothing to do with the database..!

Comment: I mean I want to add record in DB with submission.

Comment: did you get the values in bean.??

Comment: Yes, I get Values. I print those values on line number 4.|
I get correct values on line 4.

Comment: what's the error when saving the object. Post it completely.

Comment: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Catching NullPointerException.

Comment: NullPointerException can be caused by many things so update your question with full Exception.

Comment: WARNING:   #{masterController.create}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{masterController.create}: java.lang.NullPointerException

WARNING:   #{masterController.create}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{masterController.create}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: you are not helping.!! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work

Comment: In other words, you have no idea when exactly a `java.lang.NullPointerException` would be thrown and needed an answer to that so that you can continue nailing down the cause?

Comment: I know when a NullPointerException would be thrown. 
In the constructor of Controller, I was initializing StudentInfo, therefore Null Exception was thrown. I removed initialization now.